# Multiple SSL enabled hosts causes nginx to reload slowly

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've set up ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key directives at the
http level of my nginx configuration. The problem I'm facing is that
starting/reloading nginx is getting slower and slower as more hosts
(server directives) are added. The server has roughly 1000 SSL-enabled
hosts that inherits the ssl certificate directives.

I know nginx verifies/checks the certificate when loading it, so I'm wondering
if nginx checks the certificate each time an SSL enabled host inherits
the shared certificate? If so, shouldn't it only check the certificate
once? According to
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html it should
cause all hosts to inherit a single memory footprint, but this doesn't
seem to be the case.

If this is a bug in nginx it may be an idea to completely disable
certificate verification if possible?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SSL uses DNS for verification. Use a local DNS caching server or host files installed on the nginx server.

Comment: I'm always willing to learn. Why is this downvoted? I realize it's probably too simple an answer for someone with 1000 sites but others might benefit. A web search for "slow ssl startup slow dns" returns Apache and other webserver docs with this same answer. DNS performance is probably not the answer to this specific question but it is a known issue that can cause slow web server startup.